# GameOver screen position swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented a game over screen to pop up when the player loses, the height is perfectly in the middle of the screen however the images stretches to the edge of the screen which i don't want it to do. I want the image to be offset from the screen slightly. I have attached my code for the game over screen below. The height is set just need help setting the width.

```
    gameOverScreen = SKSpriteNode(texture: gameOverScreenTexture)

    gameOverScreen.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    gameOverScreen.size.height = self.frame.height / 3

    gameOverScreen.zPosition = 0

    self.addChild(gameOverScreen)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to sort it out. Just changed this line:

```
  gameOverScreen = SKSpriteNode(texture: gameOverScreenTexture)
```

To this:

```
gameOverScreen = SKSpriteNode(texture: gameOverScreenTexture, size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 600))
```